# Android resource linking failed..... error: failed linking references

Tags: android, reference, linker, resources

My Android app got Unpublished from Google Play because there were a lot of permissions in the project. But now I need to update my project and while uploading to Play Store I'll declare all the permissions on the App Page.
Now I've installed Studio `3.2.1` and Imported the project but I get some problems I can't get rid off. Even after searching for the solutions on the Internet.

I get compile Errors as below:
Android resource linking failed

Output:

```
C:\VikAndProjects\VikAllInDialogs\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:740: error: resource android:attr/preserveIconSpacing is private.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\VivekTheGreat\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\04715f967a002ffd330f576b4f8cb914\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        E:\VikAndSDK\platforms\android-22\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\VikAndProjects\VikAllInDialogs\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\instant-run\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\VikAndProjects\VikAllInDialogs\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\VikAndProjects\VikAllInDialogs\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\VikAndProjects\VikAllInDialogs\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        vik.practice.allindialogs\
        -0\
        apk\
        --preferred-density\
        xxhdpi\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\VikAndProjects\VikAllInDialogs\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

I can't change or Edit anything in "....intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml" file. Once I "Run" or "Build Project" after editing the values.xml file it RETURNS to the present file.
```

Any help is Very Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look through your app's resources, similar to `app_project/app/src/main/res/values/<filename>.xml`. One of these files references `android:attr/preserveIconSpacing` - this resource is a private attribute in the android platform, so you'll need to remove it.

Comment: The project only has these 4 files in "values" folder i.e., colors, dimens, strings & style.I searched i all files in menu, raw, values and xml folder but caan't find the text preserveIconSpacing.

Comment: Did you check the styles.xml file? That's the most likely candidate. If that doesn't have the reference, see what's in the line mentioned by the error in the intermediate file, i.e.: `app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml` line 740. The name of the style or styleable to which that attribute belongs to should be a good clue to where to find it. It's possible it comes from a library you're depending on. Then you can just override that style to use the proper attributes.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I Override it?

Comment: Let's say the broken resource is a style: `<style name="S1"><attr name="correct"/><attr name="android:preserveIconSpacing"/></style>`. Then you need to add to your `res/values/styles.xml`: `<style name="S1"><attr name="correct"/><attr name="preserveIconSpacing"/></style>`. Keep everything the same apart from removing the "android:" namespace.

Comment: Thanks @Izabella Orlowska for your help. I tried what you have suggested but to no Avail. Anyhow, I did start my app Fresh. With Latest Studio latest ADB, latest Gradle and all so that I'll not get any problem again Importing the projectif done after 6 months or so. 
Thanks a lot.